# ScrollView Insets does not adjust on KeyboardHide function (SWIFT3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

it seems that the ScrollView's Insets doesn't update itself on UIEdgeInsets.Zero when Keyboard Hide function gets called in swift3, but the same code gets perfectly executed in swift 2.2

```
 if isViewLoaded && view.window != nil {
        if(scrollView != nil)
        {
            scrollView!.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
            scrollView!.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        }
    }
```

or

```
        if isViewLoaded && view.window != nil {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let keyboardSize: CGSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.size {

                if(scrollView != nil)
                {
                    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(keyboardSize.height, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                    scrollView!.contentInset = contentInsets
                    scrollView!.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
                }

                self.scrollView?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
```

Any Thoughts..?

Answer (score 0):

try this for swift 3.0,

```
var contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: actually no need of that line. You can also add only first 3 lines. @Kedar

Comment: makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {

        if let keyboardSize = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
            UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
            var contentInset = self.scrollView!.contentInset
            contentInset.bottom = keyboardSize.height + adjustHeight
            self.scrollView!.contentInset = contentInset
            UIView.commitAnimations()
        }

    }  
func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {

            UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
            UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
            var contentInset = self.scrollView!.contentInset
            contentInset.bottom = 0
            self.scrollView!.contentInset = contentInset

            UIView.commitAnimations()
        }
```

Comment: nope does not work, also am wondering why are you holding the contentinset of scrollview and then you go on to set its bottom to zero then you go on to assign it to scrollview's contentinset. You can directly set it as UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)